# Cannot get file from war

Tags: java, jboss, classpath

I need to get properties file from war.

```
String fileName = loadFileName();
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI()));
    property.load(fis);
}
.........

private String loadFileName(){
    if(currentLocale.equals(new Locale("en"))){
        return "file:///locale/output/language.properties";
    } else {
        return "file:///locale/output/language_ru.properties";
    }
}
```

This files locate in main/resources/locale/output folder. Unfortunately,this approach is not working, all property values is null. How to load files from war correctly? Server: JBoss AS 7

[image]

Comment: Read the `InputStream` directly with `getResourceAsStream(fileName)` if the resource is in the right place.

Comment: Looking at your code, you might find it easier to use a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it's not helped. Maybe my path is wrong? I add picture with full path.

Comment: You need to read the javadoc of `getResource()`. It doesn't expect a URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WAR is an archive file. You can't address "files" within the archive as files. Just open the resource via `#getResourceAsStream(String name)`. `name` is probably `/locale/output/language.properties` here.

Of course you shouldn't build i18n yourself.